# SQL Query - Getting Sum Of Multiple Column with Id in Table Using Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Good day,

I'm creating a query where I can throw inside the data grid view.
Suppose I have 2 table namely table A and table B. Table A has StaffId column and while Table B has StaffId too. Table B can have multiple value of cost with foreign key of StaffId. What I'm trying to do is, get all the sum value inside the Table B with the same StaffId.

Here's the sample table definitions and contents.

```
// Table A
| StaffId | Name   |
|    1    | Dummmy |

// Table B
|   Id    | StaffId |   Cost  |
|   1     |    1    |  10.00  |
|   2     |    1    |  10.00  |
|   3     |    1    |  10.00  |
```

I already tried this query, but I can't get the correct answer.

```
SELECT A.Name, Sum(B.Cost) FROM B INNER JOIN A ON A.StaffId=B.StaffId
```

The answer should be like this

```
Dummy | 30.00
```

but my query doesn't work. How can I get the value of all the cost in the table B?

Any help would be much appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason everyone is using a `GROUP BY` is `SQL Server` is returning EVERY row where tabLE A has a match with Table B. `SUM` is an aggregate function, and only works when compressing sets kg rows. That's what the `GROUP BY` is for...smashing/compressing sets of rows together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

To find sum of cost for each and every StaffId's you should use this.

```
SELECT A.StaffId
    ,A.NAME
    ,Sum(B.Cost) as Total
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.StaffId = B.StaffId
GROUP BY A.StaffId
    ,A.NAME
```

To find all the cost for all the StaffId's you should use this.

```
SELECT Sum(B.Cost)
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.StaffId = B.StaffId
```

Comment: I think you should use `GROUP BY A.StaffId`. Two staffs can have same name.

Comment: You are right, I just now edited the post. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Again I think `GROUP BY A.StaffId` is enough. Since `StaffId` can alone uniquely identify a staff.

Comment: but user tried to fetch staffname instead of staffId I guess

Comment: What I'm trying to fetch is the total sum of the cost all the staffId inside my table

Comment: I got it now. I added as Total after your code of Sum(B.Cost) and I put as Total. Please update your answer so I can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Thank you @StackUser :) have a great day! God bless +